# Rails: handle large menu lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have very large menu lists, that appear on every single page and also need to be updated according to user input. Additionally, I have live search implemented, to dynamically filter these lists.
What is the best approach to handle those in terms of performance?

Comment: give an example of your menu list. without we cant help you!

Answer (score 0):

I using a [managed search service](http://websolr.com) might be a good idea for your case. Or add indexes?